# wp_mail use WordPress's default email template for sending email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Is there any way to send email from WordPress using the default template that WordPress uses for sending emails (on registration, password reset etc).

I'm using `wp_mail` function for sending email, but how to include the template in the message with custom contents.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use custom template?

Comment: Yes, but not custom, the one that WordPress uses with a blue background header.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this tutorial: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-change-sender-name-in-outgoing-wordpress-email/

---

You will need to add the following code in your theme’s functions.php file or a site-specific plugin.

```
// Function to change email address

function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'tim.smith@example.com';
}

// Function to change sender name
function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return 'Tim Smith';
}

// Hooking up our functions to WordPress filters 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wpb_sender_name' );
This code simply replaces the default WordPress sender name and email address with your custom sender name and email address.
```

Comment: I think this misses the question completely. OP not asking how to change sender's name, he is asking how to make wp_mail function use worpdress email template.